# PayPal REST API creates readonly invoices

Tags: rest, paypal, invoice

Our application created an invoice using the PayPal REST API. I then navigated to the newly created invoice on the PayPal site and discovered the following message:

[image: This invoice cannot be edited on the web. Please edit the invoice using the original tool you used to create this invoice.]

Only basic actions can be taken on the invoice (Archive, Cancel, Remind). Our goal was to initiate invoices, then the user could use the PayPal site to verify/edit before sending. Is it possible to allow the user to edit and send invoices created by apps?

For reference: [PayPal REST API Invoicing Overview](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/invoicing/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm finding the same thing with the Classic API.  It looks like the only way to update invoices created over the API is to use the UpdateInvoice API.

Comment: I'm also fairly sure this is the case. I was hoping for an undocumented toggled that could be passed in.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an invoice from one client(let's say mobile app) and update it on PayPal site or, any other PayPal invoicing client applications. If you want to edit the same invoice, you will have to use the same client application with which you created the invoice. You can use PUT /v1/invoicing/invoices/{id} [API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#update-an-invoice) to update the invoice(you may be already aware of the same).

The reason behind the same is there is an application id attached to the created invoice and it should be updated via the same application id. That is the design decision PayPal Invoicing team has taken due to the security issues.